# An Import-Package could not be resolved Error in Deploying Flex UI project

Tags: eclipse, vmware, vsphere, eclipse-virgo

I am developing simple VSphere Web Client plugin in Eclipse Juno with Vijava 5.5 and Vsphere sdk 5.5.. My project was working fine till yesterday. Today I tried to change the sdk to Vsphere sdk 6.0. From that onwards I am getting Following Error while deploying my UI project in Virgo Server.

Later, I again reverted to my Vsphere sdk 5.5 itself. **But still i am getting this error. I don't know what I missed. Why it showing in my UI project? Is there anything i can change my dependencies there?**

Error is,

```
2015-06-11 19:27:26.160] [INFO ] TCP Connection(11)-127.0.0.1  <DE0004I> Starting bundle 'test-provider' version '0.0.0'.

[2015-06-11 19:27:26.160] [INFO ] start-signalling-1            <DE0005I> Started bundle 'test-provider' version '0.0.0'. 

[2015-06-11 19:27:26.957] [INFO ] TCP Connection(11)-127.0.0.1  <DE0000I> Installing bundle 'com.mycompany.testui.testui' version '1.0.0'. 

[2015-06-11 19:27:27.051] [INFO ] TCP Connection(11)-127.0.0.1  <ME0003I> Dump 'C:\ProgramData\vmware\vSphere Web Client\serviceability\dump\2015-06-11-19-27-051' generated 

[2015-06-11 19:27:27.066] [ERROR] TCP Connection(11)-127.0.0.1  <DE0002E> Installation of bundle 'com.mycompany.testui.testui' version '1.0.0' failed. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.osgi.framework.UnableToSatisfyBundleDependenciesException: Unable to satisfy dependencies of bundle 'com.mycompany.testui.testui' at version '1.0.0': Cannot resolve: com.mycompany.testui.testui
    Resolver report:
        An Import-Package could not be resolved. Resolver error data <Import-Package: com.mycompany.testprovider; version="0.0.0">. Caused by missing constraint in bundle <com.mycompany.testui.testui_1.0.0>
             constraint: <Import-Package: com.mycompany.testprovider; version="0.0.0">

    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.resolve.internal.QuasiResolveStage.process(QuasiResolveStage.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.CompensatingPipeline.doProcessGraph(CompensatingPipeline.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.internal.StandardPipeline.doProcessGraph(StandardPipeline.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.pipeline.stage.AbstractPipelineStage.process(AbstractPipelineStage.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.driveInstallPipeline(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.doInstall(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.install(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.internal.PipelinedApplicationDeployer.deploy(PipelinedApplicationDeployer.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.management.StandardDeployer.deploy(StandardDeployer.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor99.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor65.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you deploy your UI, you must deploy your service com.mycompany.testprovide previously

Answer (score 0):

Service provider is not linked with Plugin UI project. In order to do that, 
need to do the following..

Right-click on the Plugin UI project and select vSphere SDK Tools > Package vSphere Client plugin.

In that, select your service provider project. That's it.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

To make sure the service bundle is deployed before the ui bundle use the `<bundlesOrder>` tag in the `plugin-package.xml`.

vSphere Client (HTML) versions 6.5U1 and above improve on this by introducing a dedicated scope for each plugin (OSGi sandboxing feature).